# Write ActiveRecord Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am having Orders with status(Pending, and Completed), Pickup_date, dropoff_date.
And i want to order conditionally on the basis of status.

- If status is Pending, it should be order by pickup_time.
- If status is Completed, it should be order by dropoff_time.

Answer (score 1):

We can do it in single query in scope as :

```
scope :order_by_time, -> { order("CASE WHEN (orders.state IN ('pending', 'picked_up')) THEN 'orders.pick_up_time' WHEN (orders.state IN ('ready_for_delivery', 'delivered')) THEN 'orders.delivery_time' END") }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend **not** to mix scope responsibilities. If you do it all in one scope called `order_by_time`, the naming is confusing, if I see `Order.order_by_time` I will assume that it only orders the result, and I will be truly surprised when I learn the reality after checking the implementation...

I would recommend some isolation, which provides more flexibility for later use:

```
scope :pending,   -> { where(status: :pending) }
scope :completed, -> { where(status: :completed) }

scope :order_by_pickup_time, -> { order(pickup_time: :desc) }
scope :order_by_dropof_time, -> { order(dropof_time: :desc) }
```

Then you could use them:

```
Order.pending.order_by_pickup_time
Order.completed.order_by_dropof_time
```

Answer (score 0):

In the model

```
  scope :pending, -> { where(status: "pending").order(pickup_time: :desc) }
  scope :completed, -> { where(status: "completed").order(dropof_time: :desc) }
```

Then use `Order.pending` it will order by pick up time it with all pending orders
Then use `Order.completed` it will order it with all conmpleted orders by dropoff time

Answer (score 0):

[Query using conditionals](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-conditionals)

I suggest to use conditionals query

```
class Orders < ApplicationRecord
  scope :order_by_pickup_time, ->(status) { where("created_at < ?", pickup_time) if status == "pending" }
end
```

> Like the other examples, this will behave similarly to a class method.

```
class Orders < ApplicationRecord
  def self.order_by_pickup_time(status)
    where("created_at < ?", pickup_time) if status == "pending"
  end
end
```

> However, there is one important caveat: A scope will always return an ActiveRecord::Relation object, even if the conditional evaluates to false, whereas a class method, will return nil. This can cause NoMethodError when chaining class methods with conditionals, if any of the conditionals return false.